# How to use OpenCV < 3.0 or 2.4.X with Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, opencv, visual-studio-2015

OpenCV doesn't currently come with VC14 built executables and therefore does not run with Visual Studio 2015. It currently gives an error that  MSVCP120D.dll and MSVCR120D.dll is missing.

How do I get OpenCV working with VS2015?

---

Alternatively, use OpenCV > 3.1 which does come with VC14 DLLs

Comment: OpenCV 3.1 does have vc14 prebuild binaries, and works perfectly with visual studio 2015. Your answer was probably valid some time ago. Now is obsolete.

Comment: I think it's still useful for reference for those not using 3.1, but then again why are they (me) using VS2015 and not using 3.1...

Comment: Yep.. I just thought you should mention this in your answer, which otherwise would be misleading

Comment: @Miki thanks, i've updated to make it clear that this question is for 3.0 and below

Answer (score 0):

Currently the libs are built for VS2013 so there are two and a half options to using OpenCV with VS2015

1. (Half an option) The first is to ditch VS2015 completly and roll back to VS2013, this should clear up the MSVCP120 errors
2. The second is to compile the OpenCV source code using VS2015. A good question on StackOverflow for this is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33063847/opencv-with-visual-studio-2015-enterprise)

**IMHO THE BEST (Quickest) OPTION BELOW**

3. Alternatively (and this is the easiest option) if you simply *install* Visual Studio 2013 and then continue to use VS2015 all the dependancies required to run OpenCV will have been installed and you will be good to go. This means you still get C++11 support within VS2015 and the OpenCV Libs have the DLLs they need to run.